# Understanding asymptotic expansion

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I am trying to learn about asymptotic expansions. I am using the book Singular Perturbation Theory by R.S. Johnson. I have now stumbled upon an expansion that I do not understand (eq. 1.68 in the book). Here, it is stated that we may expand (with $x=O(1)$)

$$
\frac{1}{1+e^{-x/\epsilon}}\left(1-\frac{x+\epsilon}{1+e^{-x/\epsilon}}\right)\sim (1-e^{-x/\epsilon})(1-x-\epsilon)+(x+\epsilon)e^{-x/\epsilon}
$$

where we retain terms $O(1)$, $O(\epsilon)$, $O(e^{-x/\epsilon})$ and $O(\epsilon e^{-x/\epsilon})$.

How does one go about reproducing this expansion? I have tried expanding it in a Taylor series around $\epsilon=0$, but it does not lead to the same result. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The whole idea of asymptotic expansion is that there is no Taylor series in $\epsilon$ around $\epsilon=0$; so I am curious, how you calculated the series around this point.

Comment: You should define $y= e^{-x/\epsilon}$ and then do a multivariable Taylor expansion in $\epsilon$ and $y$ up to the orders indicated.

Comment: Thank you! Defining $y=e^{-x/\epsilon}$ does the trick! I should have clarified that the Taylor expansion lead nowhere, rather than saying it did not lead to the same result.